# How does spring security knows which user has been authenticated in azure ad

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am using spring boot with angular for azure ad authentication. In angular i have used Microsoft adal library for authentication. From that I am getting an access token, and passing as header with request to spring boot app. But When i am retrieving SecurityContext object, i am getting anonymous user.

Now how does spring security knows about this  user login. Do i need to explicitly do any code for this to get done?

Answer (score 0):

Configure properly `azure-spring-boot` (ad client id and secret) and then in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` filter your requests with [AADAuthenticationFilter](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-spring-boot/blob/master/azure-spring-boot/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/spring/autoconfigure/aad/AADAuthenticationFilter.java). Check out a sample [here](http://www.redbaronofazure.com/?p=7607).

Comment: I have tried using AadAuthFilter, but when I use it, It always gives me error like " consider defining a bean of type AadAuthFilter" .

Comment: My doubt is, what does the method SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() will be returning in the Azure security context?